# NullPointerException with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, media-player

Here is my code:

```
MediaPlayer a1,a2,a3...a24;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a);
    a1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a1);
    a2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a2);
    a3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a3);
             ...
    a24 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a24);
}

private void play(MediaPlayer p) {
    p.start();
}
```

The problem is that if I'm playing a1,a2,a3 everything is right, but if I'm playing a24 I get a NullPointerException. The size of the 24 audio files are about 25Kb each, so I don't think is a problem of memory consumption. I have tried putting a delay before starting play but nothing seems to help. The android documentation does not explain much about this; what should I do?

Comment: You don't need a separate MediaPlayer for each sound. Create one MediaPlayer and then play the sounds from your assets folder

Comment: @Tony How should I do this? Apparently I have to create() the MediaPlayer every time I want to play a sound, and release() it after I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually check the value of a24 after calling create()?  Is it non NULL?  I think you are running into a limit on the number of MediaPlayer objects that can be created.  There is a great post on the MediaPlayer and SoundPool here:
http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/

Comment: It is always null, regardless of the delay. Apparently I have to create() the MediaPlayer every time, and release() it after I'm done. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

descriptor = getAssets().openFd( "track name" ); 
mp.setDataSource(     descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength() ); 
descriptor.close(); 
mp.setLooping(false); 
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

You would need to reset the next time and re-setup to play again.